# Reentrant lock await and signalAll methods

Tags: java, locks, reentrantlock

Why the following very simple code does not work.. it gets stuck.. 
I am trying to use the explicit lock `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;` and its `newCondition()` method.

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class TheCondition implements Runnable {

        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

        static int variable = 2;

        public void incrementVariable() throws InterruptedException
        {
            lock.lock();
            try{    
               condition.await();
               for (int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
                         variable++;
               }
            }   
            finally
            {
               lock.unlock();
            }
        }


        public static void main (String []args) throws InterruptedException
        {
            TheCondition tc = new TheCondition();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(tc);
            t1.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            tc.incrementVariable();
            t1.join();
            System.out.println(variable);
        }

        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 0;i<100000;i++){
                variable++;     
            }
            System.out.println(variable);
            lock.lock();
            try{
                condition.signalAll();
            }
            finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am locking on the same lock so it should be working... instead it gets blocked in the main thread when it calls `incrementVariable()`.
Why would it happen such a thing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first execute `run`, which completes in a few microseconds. This method calls `signalAll` at the time when no threads are `await`ing the signal. Then, after one second, you call `incrementVariable` in the main thread, which, naturally, hangs on the `await` method, never receiving a signal.

Comment: Was about to reply myself heeh yep without Thread.sleep(10000) works fine.